# How to uninstall Jupyter notebook installed from Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I followed the following [instructions](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) to install the Jupyter notebook (Single user mode).

However, I actually need to install the multi user (Jupyter-hub) application.

How do I uninstall this application?

FYI - Using Centos 6.8

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can remove Jupyter Notebook by running:

```
conda remove jupyter jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyter-core
```

You can install Jupyterhub by running:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub
```

I believe that this package is only compatible with Python 3.

Comment: NOTE for MAC OS: My Jupyter Notebook for Mac OS X 10.14.2 folders here used an underscore, so if the above command does not work, look here `~/USER/NAME/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` for these: `jupyeter_client`, `jupyter_console`, and `jupyter_core`. If those are there simply run `conda remove jupyter jupyter_client jupyter_console jupyter_core`

Answer (score 5):

I had to use:

```
conda uninstall jupyter_core nbformat nbconvert notebook
```