# Uninstalled all pip, Homebrew, and Anaconda packages, but Jupyter Notebook still works

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed Jupyter either through pip, Homebrew, or Anaconda. My packages and stuff are all getting messed up, so I want to completely start over from scratch as if I got a new computer. I followed instructions for uninstall pip, Homebrew, and Anaconda packages, but running jupyter notebook in Terminal still works.

Any help to kind of reset my computer?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Add information about OS you are using. Answers could be very different for Ubuntu/Windows/Arch/Gentoo/MacOS/etc

Comment: I suppose it could be more productive for you just install jupyter into fresh virtualenv. My recomendation to use `pipenv` : `pip install pipenv&& mkdir new_jupyter && cd new_jupyter && pipenv install jupyter && pipenv shell`

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling the installing software (like `pip`, `homebrew`, or `anaconda`) won't uninstall things you installed with it. What to do to fix this depends on what you used to install jupyter notebook, but the first step is to reinstall the installer you used. Then:

---

If you used `pip`, get `pip` again and run this command:

```
pip uninstall jupyter
```

You might have to do this instead:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall jupyter
```

---

If you used Homebrew, do this:

```
brew uninstall jupyter
```

---

If you used Anaconda you should do this (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327052/how-to-uninstall-jupyter-notebook-installed-from-anaconda)):

```
conda remove jupyter jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyter-core
```

Comment: Do you believe it will work for every possible OS? MacOS/Ubuntu/Windows/Gentoo/Manjaro/etc?

Comment: @Ingaz *IF* @John used `pip`, then I believe so.

Comment: @Ingaz I don't know at the moment, I am actively trying to figure that out and I will edit my answer when I do.

Comment: OP wrote about anaconda and homebrew. He did not remember exactly how he installed

Comment: @Ingaz Added another part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186691/discussion-between-ingaz-and-ethan-k).

Comment: I tried all of these things and the `jupyter notebook` command *still* works. I've uninstalled Python, so the kernel doesn't work, but I, too, would like to wipe the slate clean and start from scratch. Is this even possible? I'm running macOS Catalina.

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052232/how-to-uninstall-jupyter) worked for me to completely uninstall jupyter